# Stream data from an EventEmitter class - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, eventemitter

I'd like to know if is it possible to create a readable stream in some way with the data emitted by an EventEmitter.

For example, I have a RandomNumberGenerator that inherits from EventEmitter that has this function:

```
emitData: =>
clearTimeout @timeout

return unless @running

data = _.chain @types
  .map (type) => [type, @chance[type]() if @chance[type]]
  .object()
  .value()

@emit "data", data

@timeout = setTimeout @emitData, @interval
```

So in another file, I can write:

```
numberGenerator.on 'data', (data) ->
   console.log(data)
```

Now I'd like to pipe this generated numbers in another stream. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

just use this: target.write(data)